# Incoherence between oscilloscope and spectrum analyser

Tags: oscilloscope, spectrum-analyzer

There seems to be an incoherence between what I see with my oscilloscope, and what I see with my spectrum analyser.

I have a signal of about 1MHz (if I'm not wrong), 5mV, from an antenna, through RG174 coaxial. It is clearly seen in the following picture of my oscilloscope screen.

[image]

Then I connect the same cable to my spectrum analyser, and see nothing like this apparently (see next picture).

Is my spectrum analyser damaged, or am I missing some point ?

Additional information:

OSCILLOSCOPE: AC, 50 ohm, 1ns/div, 5mv/div

SPECTRUM: 50 ohm, start frequency 500kHZ, stop frequency 15MHz, ref level 1mV, attenuation 0db, 10 db/div, set in average mode for clarity, but the same problem subsist in non average mode.

[image]

Comment: 1ns/div, and a bit more then 1 division top to top on the waveform, isn't that nearly a GHz?

Comment: @Unimportant is right, 1.2ns =~ 833Mhz

Comment: All of these types of questions should have the instrument's model numbers listed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your oscilloscope shows an oscillation with a frequency in the \$\frac{1}{1\,\text{ns}}=1\,\text{GHz}\$ range. (So, yes, you're wrong, that's not a 1 MHz oscillation. I'm jealous of your oscilloscope, by the way.)

Your spectrum analyzer is set to cover 400 kHz to 15.14 MHz. You can't see a GHz oscillation in that range.

Comment: Oh I am stupid !

Comment: no, you're (probably) not, mistakes just happen!